# Project Euler#61: Cyclical figurate numbers

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, programming-challenge

[Project Euler Problem 61](https://projecteuler.net/problem=61) asks:

> Triangle, square, pentagonal, hexagonal, heptagonal, and octagonal numbers are all figurate (polygonal) numbers and are generated by the following formulae:
>
> $$\begin{array}{lll}
> \textrm{Triangle}  & P_{3,n}=n(n+1)/2  & 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, \ldots\\
> \textrm{Square}   & P_{4,n}=n^2  & 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, \ldots\\
> \textrm{Pentagonal}  & P_{5,n}=n(3n−1)/2  & 1, 5, 12, 22, 35, \ldots\\
> \textrm{Hexagonal}  & P_{6,n}=n(2n−1)  & 1, 6, 15, 28, 45, \ldots\\
> \textrm{Heptagonal}  & P_{7,n}=n(5n−3)/2  & 1, 7, 18, 34, 55, \ldots\\
> \textrm{Octagonal}  & P_{8,n}=n(3n−2)  & 1, 8, 21, 40, 65, \ldots
> \end{array}$$
>
> The ordered set of three 4-digit numbers: 8128, 2882, 8281, has three interesting properties.
>
> 1. The set is cyclic, in that the last two digits of each number is the first two digits of the next number (including the last number with the first).
> 2. Each polygonal type: triangle \$(P_{3,127}=8128)\$, square \$(P_{4,91}=8281)\$, and pentagonal \$(P_{5,44}=2882)\$, is represented by a different number in the set.
> 3. This is the only set of 4-digit numbers with this property.
>
> Find the sum of the only ordered set of six cyclic 4-digit numbers for which each polygonal type: triangle, square, pentagonal, hexagonal, heptagonal, and octagonal, is represented by a different number in the set.

While revising my previous solutions to bound under 5 seconds (because this is the most logical limit for any project Euler solution, otherwise the algorithm is flawed or not the best) I came to this which runs in around 10-15 seconds (peak at 12).

I have tried to make it better but I can't think of any remarkable improvements yet.

```
    static Stack<Integer> figurateStack;

    public static int get61() {
    figurateStack = new Stack<Integer>();
    int count = -1;
    int i = 1111;// minimum
    final int n = 6;
    final int low_lim = 3;
    int[] a = new int[n];
    boolean flag = false;// flag to use as a stepback conjugate
    boolean stepback = false;
    do {
        flag = false;
        if (count < n - 2) {
            for (; i < 9999; i++) {
                if (isSpecialFigurate(i, low_lim, low_lim + (n - 1))) {
                    if (count == -1 || (count >= 0 && i / 100 == a[count] % 100) && i > 1000) {
                        ++count;
                        a[count] = i;
                        break;
                    } else {
                        figurateStack.pop();
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            i = (i % 100) * 100 + a[0] / 100;
            if (isSpecialFigurate(i, low_lim, low_lim + (n - 1))) {
                ++count;
                a[count] = i;
                break;
            } else {
                stepback = true;
            }
        }
        if (i == 9999) {
            stepback = true;
        }
        if (stepback) {
            figurateStack.pop();
            i = a[count] + 1;
            --count;
            flag = true;
            stepback = false;
        }
        if (count < n - 2 && !flag) {
            i = 100 * (i % 100) + 10;
            flag = false;
        }
    } while (count < 6);
    return a[0] + a[1] + a[2] + a[3] + a[4] + a[5];
}

public static boolean isSpecialFigurate(int x, int lowlim, int upplim) {
    for (int index = lowlim; index <= upplim; index++) {
        if (!figurateStack.contains(index)) {
            long n = (long) Math.floor((Math.sqrt(8 * (index - 2) * x + (index - 4) * (index - 4)) + (index - 4)) / (2 * (index - 2)));         
            if (getFigurateNumbers(n, index) == x) {
                figurateStack.push(index);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

    public static long getFigurateNumbers(long n, int r) {
    return (n * n * (r - 2) - n * (r - 4)) / 2;
}
```

Comment: @200_success thankyou so much \* *bows* \*

Comment: You can avoid a lot of unnecessary work if you don't generate lots of useless numbers in order to push them through expensive filters; you can get away with generating each number just once, directly from its respective formula. Can't say much more than that - except perhaps for the word 'bitmask' - without spelling out the whole solution and robbing you of the amazing buzz of discovery...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
boolean flag = false;//FLAG flag to use as a stepback conjugate
boolean stepback = false;
do {
    flag = false;//FLAG
    if (count < n - 2) {
        for (; i < 9999; i++) {
            if (isSpecialFigurate(i, low_lim, low_lim + (n - 1))) {
                if (count == -1 || (count >= 0 && i / 100 == a[count] % 100) && i > 1000) {
                    ++count;
                    a[count] = i;
                    break;
                } else {
                    figurateStack.pop();
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        i = (i % 100) * 100 + a[0] / 100;
        if (isSpecialFigurate(i, low_lim, low_lim + (n - 1))) {
            ++count;
            a[count] = i;
            break;
        } else {
            stepback = true;
        }
    }
    if (i == 9999) {
        stepback = true;
    }
    if (stepback) {
        figurateStack.pop();
        i = a[count] + 1;
        --count;
        flag = true;//FLAG
        stepback = false;
    }
    if (count < n - 2 && !flag) {//FLAG
        i = 100 * (i % 100) + 10;
        flag = false;//FLAG
    }
} while (count < 6);
return a[0] + a[1] + a[2] + a[3] + a[4] + a[5];
```

You've got a flag variable in there. But from what I see, you don't need it. I've labeled all the usages with `//FLAG`.

The only line that sets `flag` to true is inside the if statement `stepback`. `stepback` is triggered by `i == 9999` or some other condition earlier.

`flag` is set to `false` at the top of your do-while loop. So every iteration, it's set to false.

Because of this, the flag variable cannot be changed from false until the stepback if-statement.

So we can do this:

```
    if (stepback) {
        figurateStack.pop();
        i = a[count] + 1;
        --count;
        flag = true;//FLAG
        stepback = false;
    } else if (count < n - 2) {
        i = 100 * (i % 100) + 10;
        flag = false;//FLAG
    }
```

if stepback occured, flag is true, and the if statement thereafter becomes always false. So turn it into an else.

You don't make any other checks for `flag`, so now `flag` can be removed.

```
boolean stepback = false;
do {
    if (count < n - 2) {
        for (; i < 9999; i++) {
            if (isSpecialFigurate(i, low_lim, low_lim + (n - 1))) {
                if (count == -1 || (count >= 0 && i / 100 == a[count] % 100) && i > 1000) {
                    ++count;
                    a[count] = i;
                    break;
                } else {
                    figurateStack.pop();
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        i = (i % 100) * 100 + a[0] / 100;
        if (isSpecialFigurate(i, low_lim, low_lim + (n - 1))) {
            ++count;
            a[count] = i;
            break;
        } else {
            stepback = true;
        }
    }
    if (i == 9999) {
        stepback = true;
    }
    if (stepback) {
        figurateStack.pop();
        i = a[count] + 1;
        --count;
        stepback = false;
    } else if (count < n - 2) {
        i = 100 * (i % 100) + 10;
    }
} while (count < 6);
return a[0] + a[1] + a[2] + a[3] + a[4] + a[5];
```

Next, we can collapse the if statement `i == 9999` to be included in the stepback check:

Instead of

```
    if (i == 9999) {
        stepback = true;
    }
    if (stepback) {
```

We just do

```
    if (stepback || i == 9999) {
```

Because stepback disables itself, we don't need to worry about previous iterations of the while loop having `stepback = true`.

There's also an explicit else that we can make implicit...

```
        if (isSpecialFigurate(i, low_lim, low_lim + (n - 1))) {
            ++count;
            a[count] = i;
            break;
        } else {
            stepback = true;
        }
```

to

```
        if (isSpecialFigurate(i, low_lim, low_lim + (n - 1))) {
            ++count;
            a[count] = i;
            break;
        } 
        stepback = true;
```

Making the total code

```
boolean stepback = false;
do {
    if (count < n - 2) {
        for (; i < 9999; i++) {
            if (isSpecialFigurate(i, low_lim, low_lim + (n - 1))) {
                if (count == -1 || (count >= 0 && i / 100 == a[count] % 100) && i > 1000) {
                    ++count;
                    a[count] = i;
                    break;
                } else {
                    figurateStack.pop();
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        i = (i % 100) * 100 + a[0] / 100;
        if (isSpecialFigurate(i, low_lim, low_lim + (n - 1))) {
            ++count;
            a[count] = i;
            break;
        }
        stepback = true;
    }
    if (stepback || i == 9999) {
        figurateStack.pop();
        i = a[count] + 1;
        --count;
        stepback = false;
    } else if (count < n - 2) {
        i = 100 * (i % 100) + 10;
    }
} while (count < 6);
return a[0] + a[1] + a[2] + a[3] + a[4] + a[5];
```

Comment: Your code still uses the same generate-everything-and-apply-expensive-filters approach as the original code, which involves quite a bit of unnecessary/repeated work. Do your micro-optimisations make the code fast enough to meet ADG's target?

Comment: I... didn't check, and most likely they wont. I didn't spot the correct solution, but thought my points were at least valid as cleanup / micro-optimizations.

Comment: The points that you raised in your article are valid indeed, and I did not mean to belittle your work in any way (I know only too well how difficult it is to hone a non-trivial piece of someone else's code to make it leaner and meaner, to take it closer to its true essence). I was just curious about the result... You didn't mention it and my skills regarding mental execution of Java code are woefully inadequate for the task. I guess other readers might wonder, too, given that ADG explicitly mentioned 5 seconds. BTW - Kudos to ADG for the 're-Euler with time limit' thing. That's the spirit!